# Responsive table - div and grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid, css-tables

I want to use the div table below. in the mobile view, the arrangement is not as desired.

currently mobile displayed:

|1| |2| 
|3| |4| 
|1| |2| 
|3| |4|

but I need it:

|1| |2|
|1| |2|
|3| |4|
|3| |4|

Also, I can't get all columns to 25% in the desktop version.

```
grid-template-columns: 50% auto;
```

```
grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
```

```css
.product-info-table-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% auto;
}

.product-info-table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.product-info-table {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .product-info-table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-info-table-body {
    display: table-row-group;
  }
  .product-info-table-row {
    display: table-row;
  }
  .product-info-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="product-info-table">
  <div class="product-info-table-body">
    <div class="product-info-table-row">
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">A</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">1</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">B</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info-table-row">
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">AA</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">11</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">BB</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">22</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info-table-row">
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">AAA</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">111</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">BBB</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">222</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info-table-row">
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">AAAA</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">1111</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">BBBB</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">2222</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It is for different product descriptions. once i understand the logic behind it, i would like to be able to expand the table to 6, 10 or more rows.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting 'display' once for 'grid' , once for 'table'.
choose between 'grid' or 'table', and use the good css keywords to build and fix your Html tags.